# Return top 10 most frequently occuring values that same id as a variable. 3m+ rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

EDIT:: SOLVED I was using a for loop when a while loop was the correct option to print the results.  Many thanks to all for contributing below..    I have left all steps below for reference but here is the solution and working code.  Now to clean up my data and see how this runs with my 'not so big' data hehe!

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass);
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT brand
FROM transactions
WHERE
  id IN (SELECT id FROM transactions WHERE brand = :brand1)
    AND brand <> :brand1
GROUP BY brand
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10");
$query->bindparam(":brand1", $brand);
$query->execute();

echo "<table>";


while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['brand']."</td</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
```

To put into better context, I have transaction level sales data for which I want to do a very simple brand level basket analysis/affinity analysis.

EDIT:: actual schema and example working data below.

On my page I will have a dropdown box which will select a brand. For the purposes of this question 'Brand1'. And then execute a query which lists the top 10 most occurring brands which also appear in the table with the same id as the one selected in the dropdown.

The output based on the data would be

```
brand2
brand4
brand3
brand5
```

The table consists of 3 million rows, so I don't think I can load the lot into memory.  But even the query itsself I would know quite easily how to retrieve the top 10 most frequent values in a table.  But to do it based on whether it shares and id with a variable is beyond my current level of skill.

So I call on you experts to help me to take my next step of being able to handle big data with php/mysql. How could I word such a query.

EDIT:: Attempt 1

```
$brand = "Brand1";


$db = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass);
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT brand
FROM brand
WHERE
  id IN (SELECT id FROM brand WHERE brand = :brand1)
    AND brand <> :brand1
GROUP BY brand
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10");
$query->bindparam(":brand1", $brand);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "<table>";


for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['brand']."</td</tr>";
    $i++;
}

echo "</table>";
```

The above returns, "Brand2"  5 times.   (I'm only using small sample data like in my OP). Is it my loop that's the issue, because it did similar with both types of query suggested.  Here is the schema for reference:

```
--
-- Database: `transactions`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `brand`
--

CREATE TABLE `brand` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `brand`
--

INSERT INTO `brand` (`id`, `brand`) VALUES
(1, 'Brand1'),
(1, 'Brand1'),
(1, 'Brand2'),
(1, 'Brand3'),
(1, 'Brand4'),
(2, 'Brand1'),
(2, 'Brand2'),
(2, 'Brand3'),
(3, 'Brand1'),
(3, 'Brand2'),
(4, 'Brand1'),
(4, 'Brand2'),
(5, 'Brand1'),
(5, 'Brand2'),
(5, 'Brand4'),
(5, 'Brand5'),
(6, 'Brand2'),
(6, 'Brand3'),
(7, 'Brand1'),
(7, 'Brand2'),
(7, 'Brand3');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `brand`
--
ALTER TABLE `brand`
  ADD KEY `brand` (`id`,`brand`) USING BTREE;
```

Comment: why you think you cannot load the lot into memory?

Comment: 3 million rows is not normally considered "big data".

Comment: Remove the first fetch and put `while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {` instead of the for loop. And look at Gordon Linoff's query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would express it as

```
SELECT brand
FROM brand
WHERE
  id IN (SELECT id FROM brand WHERE brand = 'brand1')
    AND brand <> 'brand1'
GROUP BY brand
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

This avoids the cost of a JOIN and removes the user selected brand that does not appear in your example result set.

As mentioned by Gondon Linoff, indexes might improve performance greatly.

Comment: I have tried implementing this answer with the above code and loop to print, however I'm just getting "Brand2" 5 times. Many Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Try running the query directly against your database. If it's returning the proper values, the issue is in the code displaying the results. If it's not, then the query needs to be reworked.

Comment: Right on! so the query does wok perfect, it is my code. ;) thx

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you can express this as:

```
select b.brand
from brand b join
     brand b1
     on b.id = b1.id and b1.brand = 1 and b1.brand <> b.brand
group by b.brand
order by count(*) desc
limit 10;
```

You'll get some benefit in performance from an index on `brand(brand, id)` as well as `brand(id)`.

Depending on the data and user requirements, I'm not sure that you'll get the performance that you want from this query.  But, first get the logic to work, then work on performance.

Comment: +1 for suggesting indexing for performance. Will definitely use this. Your query did work, however it also displayed the selected brand.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query below says "return only 10 records, start on record 16 (OFFSET 15)":

```
SELECT * FROM <YOURTABLE> LIMIT 10 OFFSET 15
```